# How to implement Android Lollipop Curved Motion APIs?

Tags: android, android-animation, material-design

I am trying to implement a curved motion effect, per 
http://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html#CurvedMotion

This is my code, and it just animates my view linearly from my starting co-ords to my ending co-ords - no curve. What am I missing?

```
    HomeView homeView = (HomeFragment) adapter.getFragmentAtPosition(MainTab.HOME.getPositionId());
    //ending x co-ordinates
    float x1 = fab.getX();
    float y1 = fab.getY();

    //ending x co-ordinates
    float x3 = homeView.getCenterXofStatusCard(fab);
    float y3 = homeView.getCenterYofStatusCard(fab);

    final Path path = new Path();
    path.moveTo(x1, y1);

    final float x2 = (x3 + x1) / 2;
    final float y2 = (y3 + y1) / 2;
    path.cubicTo(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3);

    ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(fab, View.X, View.Y, path);
    anim.start();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was using co-ordinates that generated a straight bezier curve. Here are better co-ordinates to create a curve.

```
        path.moveTo(x1, y1);
        final float x2 = (x1 + x3) / 2;
        final float y2 = y1;

        path.quadTo(x2, y2, x3, y3);
```

Comment: You could use arcTo method in Path to create a curve, right?